# How add built-in textarea in theme development?

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-options

How can I add built-in textarea instead simple textarea in Wordpress v4 like when I hit Post -> Add new in theme development? I need to add it to theme options page https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called wp editor, which uses tinymce editor and odds. This editor can be called using `wp_editor` function.

To display it on your options page, use wp_editor(); Like -

```
$field_value = get_option('a_custom_textarea');
$field_name = 'a_custom_textarea';

wp_editor( $field_value, $field_name );
```

Ref - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor